# how to prove the kernel of a matrix is 0 if a linear transformation of this matrix is surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening everyone,
I have a question of linear algebra, if $M \in Mat_{nxn}(k)$ and $\phi_M:K^n \to K^n$ a linear transformation which sends $v \in K^n$ to $Mv$. Prove that if $\phi_M$ is subjective then $ker(M)=0$.

I have no idea where shall I begin with, can someone give me some help? thanks in advance.

Comment: What can you say about the map if it's not surjective? What will the dimension of the image be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows directly from the rank-nullity theorem. For a more direct proof, consider a basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ of $K^n$. As $\phi_M$ is surjective, there exist $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ such that $\phi_M(v_i) = e_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.
These $v_i$ are linearly independent (why?) and as a consequence the kernel must be $0$.

Comment: thank you very much, I used rank-nullity for other question, but this one I got no idea, thanks a lot!